# WordPress Override de Widgets

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-widget

quiero modificar el código del Widget (**widget_search**) pero no encuentro como hacer la llamada al Widget en mi function.php y poder modificarlo, alguien me podría ayudar?

Lo que quiero es poder cambiar el código de ese widget.

Un saludo.

**Actualizacion.**

Lo que quiero es por ejemplo el widget del buscado genera este HTML

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="....">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Buscar:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Y yo quiero hacer un override para que en vez de que salga ese codigo salga el siguiente.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="...">
    <div class="col-12">
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Me he explicado mejor ahora ?

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. ¿Realmente quieres modificar el código de los widget? (No es una buena idea). Supongo que lo que quieres es añadir alguna funcionalidad o añadir un widget o algo así ¿? Por favor aclara el problema y de paso muestra lo que has intentado y dónde te está fallando. Gracias.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta.

Comment: O sea, ¿lo que quieres es poner el div así: `<div class="col-12">` y nada más?

Comment: Quiero hacer más cosas esto solo era un ejemplo.